# Applications are not opening in normal user session

Tags: dbus

Applications such as thunderbird, firefox, scheduled task

are not starting in normal user session unless i have to open terminal and login as a root, after that i have to type thunderbird, then thunderbird will open. After opening from root it show following error:-
[image]

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install dbus-x11
```

Check this out and reboot this will start the dbus daemon